# What is the implementation of the state in superdense coding?

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, superdense-coding

What is the implementation of quantum superdense coding protocol if the sender and receiver share the entangled state 
$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (\left| 01 \right> -  \left| 10\right>)
$?

Answer (score 2):

If you apply $\mathrm{X}$ on second qubit, you will get state
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle - |11\rangle)
$$

After that you can apply $\mathrm{Z}$ on second qubit as well to get Bell state $\beta_{00}$:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)
$$

Now you can employ superdense conding as usual.

*Note: matrix description of above mentioned operations is $(\mathrm{I}\otimes\mathrm{Z})(\mathrm{I}\otimes\mathrm{X})$.*

Here is a circuit for doing all mentioned above:

[image: Circuit]

A first part prepares state $|\psi_0\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|01\rangle - |10\rangle)$. This is an initial state you questioned about. Second part changes $|\psi_0\rangle$ to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$, i.e. Bell state $\beta_{00}$. Now you can apply superdense coding as usual - this is symbolized by gates $\mathrm{X}$ and $\mathrm{Z}$ (of course, application of these gates depends on two bits you want to encode, e.g. for encoding string 00 you will apply neither gate). Last part is measuring in Bell basis - again usual part of superdense coding.

Comment: your answer in which case ? I need transmit bit in cases 00 ,01,10,11 and which gate I will apply for each one. @Martin Vesely

Comment: @Ba.Taj: My construction changes your state to $\beta_{00}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|00\rangle + |11\rangle)$. After that you can apply $X$ and $Z$ gates to do coding as you are used to from "normal superdense coding".

Comment: could you please draw circuit for implementation of the above given state ,and I would appreciate if you could elaborate it extensively in advance thank you, @Martin Vesely

Comment: @Ba.Taj: See edited question.